# K-convexity on a line that does not satisfy the partial order

Tags: inequality, convex-optimization

In Convex Optimization by Stephen Boyd [Chapter 3 page 110](https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=mYm0bLd3fcoC&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=Many%20of%20the%20results%20for%20convex%20functions%20have%20extensions%20to%20K-convex%20functions.%20As%20a%20simple%20example,%20a%20function%20is%20K-convex%20if%20and%20only%20if%20its%20restriction%20to%20any%20line%20in%20its%20domain%20is%20K-convex.&source=bl&ots=tebRuJNAO0&sig=ACfU3U2QtJcGcoyv72IYeVLXtrZYr9BH4w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq1cDlucvpAhXL3KQKHff7DYUQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Many%20of%20the%20results%20for%20convex%20functions%20have%20extensions%20to%20K-convex%20functions.%20As%20a%20simple%20example%2C%20a%20function%20is%20K-convex%20if%20and%20only%20if%20its%20restriction%20to%20any%20line%20in%20its%20domain%20is%20K-convex.&f=false):

“Many of the results for convex functions have extensions to K-convex functions. As a simple example, a function is K-convex if and only if its restriction to any line in its domain is K-convex.”

**Question:**
Should it not be:

“Many of the results for convex functions..... if and only if its restriction to any **K-convex line** in its domain is K-convex.”

Because just saying **any line** may violate the proper cone condition. Since every line Segment inside the cone, not necessarily satisfies the generalized inequality induced by proper cone.

Or what I am failing to understand?